# DynamoDB updating a HasMany relation

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I am working on a project that will be using DynamoDB and I am a little confused on how to update a document that has an attribute that contains an array of items.

I am looking to use this NPM module https://www.npmjs.org/package/dynamodb-model

Example Schemas

```
# User Schema
{
  "identifier": "String",
  "email": "String",
  "referral_token": "String",
  "campaign_id": "Number",
  "first_name": "String"
  "last_name": "String",
  "gender": "String",
  "birth_date": "String",
  "username": "String",
  "mobile_number": "String",
  "postal_code_text": "String",
  "classification": "String",
  "delivery_email": "Boolean",
  "delivery_sms": "Boolean",
  "authentications": [{Authentication Schema}]
}

# Authentication Schema
{
    "provider": "String",
    "uid": "String",
    "oauth_token": "String",
    "oauth_token_secret": "String",
    "nickname": "String"
}
```

Comment: Is an array of Strings insufficient? Also, please detail how you plan to use the "authentications" attribute. If you just plan to read it and overwrite the previous value, you don't need to do anything special.

Answer (score 0):

As kurtzbot pointed out, you can just store them as an array. Even better you can use the new JSON document model. It would handle array serialization/deserialization for you. 
http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/dynamodb-update-json-and-more/

On the other hand, if one user can have a LOT of "authentications", I would suggest designing the schema like this to avoid hotspot problem:

```
User table: just like the tables you already have, without authentications fields

Auth table: same table you already have

user-auth table: User.identifier as hashkey, Authentication.uid as range key.
```

With this schema, inserting a new auth for a user won't require reading any existing user-auth pairs.